# Send header in HTTP post request in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, http, post

first of all i have `LoginPageModel` to run HTTP post request like this

```
class LoginPageModel {
  String CODD_VALU;

  String CODD_DESC;

  LoginPageModel({required this.CODD_VALU, required this.CODD_DESC});

  static Future<LoginPageModel> connect(String CODD_VALU) async {
    Uri url = Uri.parse("http://deltaprima.rmdoo.com/api/office/all");

    var response = await http.post(
      url,
      headers: {
        "CompanyCode": "MW",
      },
    );

    var dataJson = jsonDecode(response.body);
    debugPrint(dataJson);

    return LoginPageModel(
      CODD_VALU: dataJson["CODD_VALU"],
      CODD_DESC: dataJson["CODD_DESC"],
    );
  }
}
```

Then i run `LoginPageModel` on `initState` class. Like this

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
  
    LoginPageModel.connect("MW").then((value) {
      print(value);
    });
  }
```

But i cant get the Print of the value on my debugConsole, and the "CompanyCode" must send trough headers. im also trying postman, it worked and get the data from api like this.

```
[
    {
        "CODD_DESC": "DELTA PRIMA",
        "CODD_VALU": "01"
    }
]
```

But i cant get data from API using my flutter app. How

Comment: Are you doing a post request without a body?

Comment: `http` library will convert header to lower case automatically, make sure your API can read lower case header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using post is not strictly necessary, you can use get instead.

```
      String url ='http://deltaprima.rmdoo.com/api/office/all';
      var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url), 
      headers: {
      "CompanyCode": "MW",
       });
```

Moreover, please check if you're using get or post method in postman.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Future<UserData> getLoginApi(
      userEmail, userPassword, deviceType, deviceId, socialtype) async {
    late UserData userData;
 
    const url = 'Add URL';
    String email = userEmail;
    String password = userPassword;
    String devicetype = deviceType;
    String device_id = deviceId;
    String socialType = socialtype;

    final request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse(url));
    request.fields['email'] = email;
    request.fields['password'] = password;
    request.fields['devicetype'] = devicetype;
    request.fields['device_id'] = deviceId;
    request.fields['social_type'] = socialType;

    final response = await request.send();

    if (response.statusCode < 300) {
    
      final jsonResponse = await response.stream.bytesToString();
      userData = UserData.fromJson(jsonDecode(jsonResponse));
      User user = userData.user;
      String name = user.name;
      String email = user.email;
      String userId = user.userId;
      String accessToken = user.accessToken;
      print('Name : $name');
      print('email : $email');
      print('userId : $userId');
      print('accessToken : $accessToken');
    } else {
      print('Error: ${response.statusCode}');
      print(await response.stream.bytesToString());
    }

    return userData;
  }
```